# Testing connectiong with db, tests passes but no new instance in db created

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

**What I wan to do:** I want to test if my app is connecting correctly with db. In order to do so I was using these tutorials:  http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing http://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source So I'm creating new testUser, saving it and checking if user found by userName is equal to the one I've saved.

**What is not working:** even though the test passes, no new user appears in database. I don't know why. Any suggestions?

Test:

```
package com.shareabook.integration.user;

import com.shareabook.constants.initialNumberOfPoints;
import com.shareabook.model.Points;
import com.shareabook.model.User;
import com.shareabook.repository.PointsRepository;
import com.shareabook.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.shareabook.repository.UserRepository;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class userTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PointsRepository pointsRepository;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Test
    public void whenFindByUserName_thenReturnUser() {
        //given
        User testUser = new User();

        // Creates new points instance
        Points points = new Points();
        points.setAmountOfPoints(initialNumberOfPoints.INITIAL_NUMBER_OF_POINTS.getInitialNumberOfPoints());
        pointsRepository.save(points);
        int tempId = points.getId();

        testUser.setUserName("userName");
        testUser.setFirstName("firstName");
        testUser.setLastName("lastName");
        testUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("P@ssword123"));
        testUser.setEmail("emal@email.com");
        testUser.setIsBlocked(false);
        testUser.setIdpoints(tempId);
        testUser.setRoles(Arrays.asList(roleRepository.findByRole("USER")));

        userRepository.save(testUser);

        //when
        User found = userRepository.findByUserName(testUser.getUserName());

        //then
        assertThat(found.getUserName()).isEqualTo(testUser.getUserName());


    }
}
```

**------EDIT---------**
After helpful suggestions in comments I changed my test a bit and now it's working as expected.

```
package com.shareabook.integration.user;

import com.shareabook.constants.initialNumberOfPoints;
import com.shareabook.model.Points;
import com.shareabook.model.User;
import com.shareabook.repository.PointsRepository;
import com.shareabook.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.shareabook.repository.UserRepository;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class userTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PointsRepository pointsRepository;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Test
    public void whenFindByUserName_thenReturnUser() {
        //given
        User testUser = new User();

        // Creates new points instance
        Points points = new Points();
        points.setAmountOfPoints(initialNumberOfPoints.INITIAL_NUMBER_OF_POINTS.getInitialNumberOfPoints());
        pointsRepository.save(points);
        int tempId = points.getId();

        testUser.setUserName("userName");
        testUser.setFirstName("firstName");
        testUser.setLastName("lastName");
        testUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("P@ssword123"));
        testUser.setEmail("emal@email.com");
        testUser.setIsBlocked(false);
        testUser.setIdpoints(tempId);
        testUser.setRoles(Arrays.asList(roleRepository.findByRole("USER")));

        userRepository.save(testUser);

        //when
        User found = userRepository.findByUserName(testUser.getUserName());

        //then
        assertNotNull(found);
        assertEquals(testUser.getUserName(), found.getUserName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if it has to do with the DataJpaTest annotation. From the docs(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) - "By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest will use an embedded in-memory database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured DataSource)." It sounds like you are expecting actual changes to be made in your database, but I suspect you are actually querying against an in memory one.

Comment: @NickDeFazio, thank you, you and SimonMartinelli were right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DataJpaTest will configure an in-memory embedded database, scan for @Entity classes and configure Spring Data JPA repositories.

**It is transactional but will rollback at the end of each test!**

That's why you don't have data in your database.

Comment: Thank you, @SimonMartinelli. So to sum it up - I'm testing operations on in memory database not an actual connection to my database, yes?

Comment: Yes as long as you haven't configured anything else